# how to pick value from a uitableview and show it on previous page on a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

i want to use uitableview just like a uipickerview. on click a button the uitableview comes.and on clicking any cell the selected value will be shown on the button on previous page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way to pass data back to another controller is to use a `delegate` protocol. The controller with the button would implement the protocol method(s) declared in an `@protocol` declaration put in the .h file of the table view controller. In the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you would call the delegate method, passing the value of the clicked on cell.

Comment: my problem is still there..can u please give me your email id that i can send that code to u because i haven't used protocol before it looks tough

Comment: @VivekSehrawat, my email is rdelmar@comcast.net. The proper response, when an answer doesn't give you enough information, is to ask for a clarification, not to unaccept it.

Answer (score 0):

rdelmar is correct, the simplest way to do this would probably be to use a delegate protocol and pass the selected value back to the previous view.

--

**However**, supposing you wanted to store this value outside of the table view and the picker, you could create a singleton or use NSUserDefaults to avoid having to pass the value around and potentially losing something. If this tableview/picker was in a settings menu or the like, that's what I would do.

See this for basics:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Some code for delegation; A protocol in your tableview class:
`@protocol SelectionDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)setSelectedTableCellValue:(NSString*)value;@end` Have your previous view confirm to and be the delegate for the tableview that you wish to display and also implement the protocol method. Now on cell selection, just retrieve the value for the cell and pass it over to your delegate via `[delegate setSelectedTableCellValue:<some cell value>];` HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look into core data, you will be able to save the data and re-access the data/value and reload in into any view controller you like. It is a very versatile tool, and once you learn it, you will be able to do so many things a lot easier. Take a look at this [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath  animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.m_TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.m_SavedDictionary setObject:cell.textLabel.text forKey:@"driver"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and on ViewwillAppear method of previous view use;

```
if([[appDelegate.m_SavedDictionary objectForKey:@"driver"]length]>=1)
{
    [m_driverButton setTitle:[appDelegate.m_SavedDictionary objectForKey:@"driver"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Thats it.